# Searching for European Scifi Comic (80s-90s) about flight to new earth

Tags: story-identification, comics

Anyone know the title of a European comic (I think it is either French or Belgian) that has this story:

- Earth is environmentally unsustainable
- Survivor living on space in some kind of station with state of disrepair
- They found a big starship on the earth , shaped like [TTA Interstellar Queen](http://www.bisbos.com/sf_tta_c_iqueen.html)
- They used the ship and took people out from the station to seek new earth
- A fight ensued from the opposing faction
- Journey to the new earth rift with dangers
- Arrived at new earth, resettled people, happy ever after
- a 2 part story , part one depicting life on space habitat and the finding of ancient space craft shaped like Interstellar Queen / Firefly / dinosaur shaped.. part 2 depicting the journey to the new earth , one notable incident they find a sarcophagus in space with a humanoid mummy inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comic you mentioned is called "Kronos", by Pierre Dupuis.

The sarcophagus you mentioned are a fleet of alien spaceships which looked like ancient egyptian coffin , with humanoid alien still alive inside.. they numbered like thousands

here's a link to the book cover

https://pmcdn.priceminister.com/photo/Dupuis-Pierre-Kronos-Livre-70439430_L.jpg

Comment: Could you also add a picture of the cover, and mention why you think this is the answer? For instance, add a synopsis?